# Offset function in excel to skip 0s and sum a dynamic range of rows

Tags: excel, offset

I am trying to use offset function in excel to dynamically calculate sales since launch of products (3 months after, 6 months after etc.). For eg. for item 1 first 3 months of sale is 2557+10000+14487= 27044 and similarly for item 2 first 3 months sale will be 2557+11853+14487=28897

Any guidance on this is super appreciated!!

| Items | Item1 | Item2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jan-20 | 0 | 0 |
| Feb-20 | 0 | 0 |
| Mar-20 | 0 | 0 |
| Apr-20 | 0 | 0 |
| May-20 | 0 | 2557 |
| Jun-20 | 0 | 11853 |
| Jul-20 | 0 | 14487 |
| Aug-20 | 0 | 11375 |
| Sep-20 | 0 | 10938 |
| Oct-20 | 0 | 10842 |
| Nov-20 | 0 | 15132 |
| Dec-20 | 0 | 19820 |
| Jan-21 | 2557 | 20726 |
| Feb-21 | 10000 | 25072 |
| Mar-21 | 14487 | 28897 |
| Apr-21 | 11375 | 28665 |
| May-21 | 10938 | 42358 |
| Jun-21 | 10842 | 25619 |
| Jul-21 | 15132 | 20575 |
| Aug-21 | 19820 | 23315 |
| Sep-21 | 20726 | 21346 |
| Oct-21 | 25072 | 19377 |

Comment: Why not just use `SUMIFS`? It's rather good for this kind of date logic.

Comment: Yes don't use `OFFSET()` Function since its not just volatile but also slows down the functionality of Excel Engine. Use as mentioned above ^^^

Comment: Thanks @BigBen. I think for SUMIFs I need to provide the range of dates in the calculation, which may not be most efficient way to do when I have 100+ products.

Comment: Then why not use either Pivot Table or Power Query here?

Comment: Thanks @MayukhBhattacharya! I am open to other solutions, just that ignore the dates column because for 100+ products each product will have different launch date. That's why I was thinking that Offset() will be easier.

Comment: You don't need to provide the range of dates, use `>` and `<` for example. If you don't want to do that, you can use `INDEX`. But really, avoid OFFSET`.

Comment: @BigBen could you please provide an example? Let's say when I have this data in A1 in the sheet.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, avoid offset. You could use index/match for example:

```
=SUM(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(0,B:B)+1):INDEX(B:B,MATCH(0,B:B)+3))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment! For 6months sum, all I have to do is change 3 at the end of the formula to 6.  This works great.